# View getting null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have an activity having a viewpager, this viewpager contains Fragment A and Fragment B.
Fragment B has also a viewpager which contains for example a C Fragment.
Fragment C implements an inner interface OnNextButtonListener of Fragment B.

FragmentB.java:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment{
    private OnNextButtonListener mFragmentCListener;
    private Button mNextButton;
    //instance variables
    //other methods
    @Override
    View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,      container, false);
        init(view);//initialize views
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
             //mFragmentCListener is instance of FragmentC casted to   OnNextButtonListener
             mFragmentCListener.onNextButtonClick();
        });
    return view;
    }

    public interface OnNextButtonListener{
       void onNextButtonClick();
    }
}
```

FragmentC.java:

```
public class FragmentC extends Fragment implements OnNextButtonListener{
  //...
  private EditText mEditText;
   @Override 
   View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container, false);
    init(view);//initialized mEditText and it is not null on rotation 
    return view;
  }
  @Override
  void onNextButtonClick(){
     String text = (String)mEditText.getText();//mEditText gets null on rotation
     //...
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine but when the device is rotated and then mNextButton(Fragment B) is clicked, mEditText(Fragment C) in onNextButtonClick gets null but its still not null in onCreateView.
I debugged the first line in onNextButtonClick and the debugger showed me [debugger.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XspCt.png)

Comment: When the device is rotated,fragments are destroyed.

Comment: I know but onCreateView is called after rotation..so?

Comment: You should `setRetainInstance(true)`  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject

Comment: the docs says "While you can store any object, you should never pass an object that is tied to the Activity, such as a Drawable, an Adapter, a View or any other object that's associated with a Context".
but in this situation, I have to retain views.

Comment: why won't you just initialize the view  in onCreate? how does init know which edit text id to get? run an if statement on init to make sure it returns something, say.. if(init(view) == null){Log.d("Fragment C","Is null")}

Comment: mEditText is not null .mEditText .getText() is null?

Comment: You should debug to check which Object is null. And do you really need to deal rotate of mobile?

Comment: all the views get null in that specific method..they're not null in onStart() and onResume()